# trying to put my node app on AWS elastic beanstalk - dashboard says Health - Degraded

Tags: amazon-web-services

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

I just uploaded my project and it says Health - Degraded.

This is my first time working with AWS, following a tutorial from egghead.io

What should I do next?

Comment: Did you check the node version, compatibility with supported node version in beanstalk? Also make sure the health check url is correct.

Comment: the node version is 4.x on beanstalk and on my machine i am using latest node.  i opened up my project with the same version and it seems to work fine.  can you please explain the health check url part?

Comment: hey nvm I got it working.  i had the start script using nodemon... turns out that was causing the issue.